# Add class to parent LI if it contains a UL with class="dropdown-menu"

Tags: jquery, html

I need to add a class `dropdown-submenu` to a parent `LI` if it has an inner `UL` element with class `dropdown-menu`. This is the example of the HTML code:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" id="menu1">
        <li>
            <a href="#">More options</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Second level link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Second level link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Second level link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Second level link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Second level link</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
</ul>
```

I didn't try anything yet because don't know how to check if `<ul class="dropdown-menu">` exists in each `LI` element. Any help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use the jQuery `.has()` [function](http://api.jquery.com/has/):

`$('li').has('ul.dropdown-menu').addClass('dropdown-submenu');`

Or use the `:has` [selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/):

`$('li:has(ul.dropdown-menu)').addClass('dropdown-submenu');`

Comment: Here is a fiddle of the function: http://jsfiddle.net/pwoidke/CHr4R
and of the selector: http://jsfiddle.net/pwoidke/frHRu

Answer (score 1):

A new option / example from me as like as last reply and you can improve for best ever.

Html is here:

```
<ul class="accordion">
    <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">2</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">a</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">b</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">4</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">a</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">x</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">y</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">z</a></li>
                    </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And javaScript codes are here:

```
$(".accordion > li:first > a").addClass("active");

    var item = $(".accordion > li").find("ul");
    if(item.length > 0){
        item.addClass("expand");
        item.find("ul").removeClass("expand").addClass("multi-expand");
        }
```

Here is the JSFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/hPfPn/

Answer (score 0):

May be this can help : -

```
$(document).ready(function()
{

    if($('li ul').hasClass('dropdown-menu'))
    {
        $(this).addClass('dropdown-submenu');
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the length of the ul with dropdown-menu class. If greater than 0 the class exists.

This should work for you:

```
if($('ul.dropdown-menu').find('li').children('ul.dropdown-menu').length > 0)
{
    var item = $('ul.dropdown-menu').find('li').children('ul.dropdown-menu');
    item.parent().addClass('dropdown-submenu');
} 
else
{
    //do something - ul has no class with name .dropdown-menu
}
```

Here is the Jsfiddle sample: http://jsfiddle.net/HvPtW/2/